# REST-API Basic Authentication and Invoke-WebRequest via Powershell

Tags: powershell, .net-core, base64, powershell-core

Trying to connect to a REST-API via Powershell client. When testing the endpoint in Postman, I have no problems at all. Here's the main part of the function (I have a `[pscredential]$Creds` parameter that I use to get the username and password):

```
[string]$username = $Creds.UserName
[string]$password = (New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Creds.UserName, $Creds.Password, 'Null')).Password
[string]$authorizationInfo= ([Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(('{0}:{1}' -f $username, $password))))

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://$($HostName)/api/" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization = ('Basic {0}' -f $authorizationInfo)}
```

For some reason the `Authorization` header is different in my script than in Postman. I can even copy the `Authorization` header out of Postman and paste it into the `-Headers` parameter and everything works fine. I just don't see where I'm getting this wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell you *why* that's not working, but I can suggest something that works for me all the time with APIs:

```
$auth = $username + ':' + $upassword
$Encoded = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($auth)
$authorizationInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($Encoded)
$headers = @{"Authorization"="Basic $($authorizationInfo)"}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://$($HostName)/api/" -Method GET -Headers $headers
```

If that doesn't work, try this subtle difference with Invoke-Restmethod:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://$($HostName)/api/" -Method GET -Headers $headers
```

Working with APIs is always an adventure.  Keep trying.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm getting the same issue with your snippet where the `$authorizationInfo` variable has a different `Base64String` than Postman (your value is the same value as my code) so it's not working. Since this value is "wrong" I'm getting an `"The supplied credentials are invalid."` message

Comment: Looks like you were right, this will be an adventure. It works fine, I just learned that the credential username is case sensitive!!

Comment: Every API seems to have its own quirks, and I wish there was a nice "lots of things to try" doc I could send you.  Occasionally I get lucky and some new API just works, but usually there is a head-meets-wall session for a while.  :)